# Toggle an appended class with radio inputs

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, toggle

I have, for example, 2 radio buttons and I want to append a class to an existing on the first selection of a radio button and then toggle the newly appended class with a click of the other radio input, without replacing the original class being replaced:

```
<input type="radio" name="color" checked="checked" value="light" />
<input type="radio" name="color" value="dark" />

<div class="tabs">
    ...
</div>
```

On checking radio with value 'dark', I want to use that .val() as a class name that gets appended to '.tabs' and, when the radio with value 'light' is sequentially checked, I want to replace 'dark' with 'light'.

This is all I have right now

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').change(function () {
                var inputVal = $("input:radio:checked").val();
                $('.tabs').append().attr('class',inputVal);
            });
        });
```

Comment: So you want to add a class to `.tabs` when you click the radio button ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.tabs').removeClass().addClass('tabs '+inputVal);` to add a class.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at it [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').change(function () {
                var inputVal = $("input:radio:checked").val();
                $('.tabs').removeClass().addClass('tabs '+inputVal);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bneG/)

> ```
> use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` along with `.on()`.
> ```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').on('change',function () {
                var inputVal = $("input:radio:checked").val();
                $('.tabs').removeClass().addClass('tabs'+inputVal);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $radioColor = $('input:radio[name=color]');
    $('.tabs').addClass($radioColor.val());

    $radioColor.on('change.changeClass', function() {
        $('.tabs').toggleClass('dark light');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**.attr()** will remove all classes and set the new class. You can then append **.tabs** class to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input').change(function () {
      var inputVal = $("input:radio:checked").val();
      $('.tabs').attr('class',inputVal).addClass('tabs');
   });
});
```